# form data upload progress using xhr javascript

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

I have written a service, which allows me to upload a given file along with a json object to a given url. My code is:

```
(function() {
    angular.module('petrofacApp')
        .service("fileUpload", fileUpload);

        function fileUpload() {

            function uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl, jsonRequest, callback){
                var fd = new FormData();
                fd.append('JsonRequestData', JSON.stringify(jsonRequest));
                fd.append('file', file, file.name);

                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

                xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
                    if (e.lengthComputable) {
                       var percentComplete = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
                       console.log(percentComplete);
                    }
                };

                xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                        callback(xhr.response);
                    }
                }; 

                xhr.open('POST', uploadUrl, true);              
                xhr.send(fd);
            }

            return {
                uploadFileToUrl: uploadFileToUrl
            }
        }
 }());
```

My problem is- if I mention the onprogress event as

```
            xhr.onprogress = function(e) {
                if (e.lengthComputable) {
                   var percentComplete = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
                   console.log(percentComplete);
                }
            };
```

file gets uploaded without any problem, but onprogress event gets triggered only once, when the upload is finished.

I found out that, to avoid this problem I have to use upload.onprogress. So I changed my code to

```
            xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
                if (e.lengthComputable) {
                   var percentComplete = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
                   console.log(percentComplete);
                }
            };
```

When I execute this, I get error-

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.xxx.xxx:6152/api/UploadFile. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405.

Please help me in solving this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to CORS. I got it fixed from the server side by installing "CORS" from  Nuget and then adding the following code to WebApi.config file

```
 var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
 config.EnableCors(cors);
```

This solved my problem.